# order of dhcp interfaces

Tags: networking, debian, dhcp, network-adapter

My debian server has two interfaces:

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp

iface eth0.40 inet dhcp
```

It gets ip-addresses and anything else from an isc-dhcp-server. (That works well in common.)

But the dhcp options differs for both interfaces (vlans).

Now the server uses the dhcp options from eth0.40 to set nameserver, routes, gateway, resolv.conf, ... But I want the server to use the dhcp options from eth0.

How can I do this?

Comment: Configure whatever you use as DHCP client to ignore nameserver/routes/gateway from `eth0`. AFAIK you cannot do that in `/etc/network/interfaces`, for example, `dhclient` needs its own configuration file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed `resolvconf` to configure the order of the interfaces.
But installing `resolvonf` solves the problem (without any extra configuration).